# Installing fascia boards on uneven roofline

Tags: repair, roof, trim, carpentry, level

I am doing some repair work on an old shed. I cut back rotted rafter tails and installed new eave trim. I plan on adding drip edge and new asphalt shingles next. When I installed the eave trim, I nailed it in following the roof line edge. However, after I installed the eave trim I noticed that there is a noticeable bow to the bottom of the eave trim. I have considered keeping the trim level at the bottom and adding drip edge at the top to hide the uneven junction between the roofline and the top of the trim.

What is the proper way to handle installing eave trim on a roofline that slightly sags in the middle (i.e. 1-2" off in the center of the roofline)?

[image]

Comment: Why is it sagging??? What's going on below?

Comment: Roofs, especially old ones, are often not straight. In fact, if you were to sight down almost any roof in your neighborhood you'd see some waviness. Is it such that it's conspicuous from any important locations?

Comment: @isherwood, it is a bit conspicuous looking from the front.

Comment: @JACK, the rafters are solid and it is a pretty solid structure. There are 1x 10's covering the roof.

Comment: You should not have this problem as the roof line should not be sagging to begin with.  Fix the root problem and you will not have trouble with your fascia boards.  I'd say that +/- 1/2" is acceptable.  +/- 2" is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options, but only one will make it look truly right without creating an oddly-shaped fascia or a ski jump in your roof. You'll need to raise the rafter tails. They're likely low in the middle because either the wall is sagging or the rafters weren't cut or fit well to begin with.

I would examine how the rafters are fastened to the wall plate. If they're not locked down hard, cut some wood wedges and begin driving them in a little at a time. Set a carpenter's line across the roof edge to act as a guide, and work each rafter up until you have a straight line.

Once everything is in place, re-fasten the rafters in some reasonable way. Hurricane ties might do, or timber screws from above.